# Using replace method on list of model objects

Tags: python, django

I want to print out a list of objects, which at the moment looks like this: `[<model.Name: value_of_field1>, <model.Name: value_of_field2>, etc]`. I would like to get only the values, so I am hoping for an outcome like:

value_of_field1, value_of_field2, etc

My attempt to do this was by using:  `list = [item.replace('model.Name: ', '') for item in list]`, however, this resulted in the following error: **'model.Name' object has no attribute 'replace'**.

How can I get a clean list, that I can later on use?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I tried using `values_list()`, however, it does not give the wanted result. My models look something like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)

class Title(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.ForeignKey(NameArchive)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.author, self.name)
```

where, author consists of 2 names. So, the values in the list (value_of_field1 etc) will look something like this - `author_first_name author_last_name, article_name` and `values_list()` gives only the last one and not all three.

Comment: Do `values()` and `values_list()` methods fit your requirements? Check doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: `Model.objects.vlaues_list()` will do it

Comment: I edited my post, as I forgot to mention how the elements of the list look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model's `__repr__()` method is reponsible for the additional `<model:Name` output that you're seeing.

You can call `__str__()` directly to give you the string representation you're after.

```
[str(o) for o in list_of_objects]
```

Comment: Did not expect it to be this simple.